# TextField onBlur with async function (react hooks)

Tags: reactjs

I am coding Signup page with react hooks.  I want my app to verify username is available when user enters username in async way and display / hide InProgress spinner during the async operation.

However, it seems like the app does not asynchronously call the function and I don't see InProgress spinner.

Here is the main code.

As you see I set setIsLoadingPage to true then run a function with await keyword then I reset setIsLoadingPage to false to hide InProgressbar.

```
const Signup = props => {


  const [emailAddressIsValidError, setEmailAddressIsValidError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoadingPage, setIsLoadingPage] = useState(false);



  const handleChangeEmailValidation = (event) => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if(!re.test(String(event.target.value).toLowerCase())){
      setEmailAddressIsValidError(true);
    }else{
      setEmailAddressIsValidError(false);
    }
  };

  const handleChangeEmailValidationOnBlur = async (event) => {
    console.log("focus... " + event.target.value);
    setIsLoadingPage(true);
    await verifyUserNameAvailable(event.target.value);
    setIsLoadingPage(false);

  };



  return (

      <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline/>
        <div className={classes.paper}>
          <div className={classes.progressBar} aria-busy={true}>
            {isLoadingPage ===true && <LinearProgress id="progressBar" />  }

          </div>
          <div className={classes.mainBox}>
            <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
              <Grid container spacing={2}>

                <Grid item xs={12}>
                  <TextField
                      variant="outlined"
                      required
                      fullWidth
                      id="email"
                      label="username"
                      error={emailAddressIsValidError}
                      name="email"
                      autoComplete="email"
                      onChange={handleChangeEmailValidation}
                      margin='dense'
                      onBlur={handleChangeEmailValidationOnBlur}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <Box mt={5}>
          <MadeWithLove/>
        </Box>
      </Container>
  );
}

export default Signup;
```

And here is a code snippet of verifyUserNameAvailable.

```
export const verifyUserNameAvailable = (email) => {


  let i = 1;
  while(i<100000){
    i = i +1;
    console.log(i)
  }

};
```

In the code above, I expect the InProgress spinner to show when user enters text and hide InProgress spinner after verifyUserNameAvailable function finishes counting.

In Actual, the UI locks up and finishes counting and no InProgress spinner is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`await` is valid when written in front of a `Promise` object.

Therefore, if you want to use the code as desired, the `modifyUserNameAvailable` function must return the `Promise` object.

If you are verifying emails by API calling , you can like this :

```
const verifyUserNameAvailable = (email) => {
   //fetch or axios or something other api call returns Promise object 
   return fetch(...);
}
```

If not :

```
const verifyUserNameAvailable = (email) => {
   //fetch or axios or something other api call returns Promise object 
   return new Promise ((resolve) => {
      //...your verifying email logic
      const available = true; //or false. Results of email availability
      resolve(available) // 
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `verifyUserNameAvailable` function. You should return a `Promise` instead of running a while. If you call a function using `await` before it, that means this function should return a promise.

That will be something like that, but instead of `setTimeout` you will put your API request.

```js
const verifyUserNameAvailable = (email) => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 3000)
});
```